# Timezones with Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I am hitting some unexpected behavior with Calendar and SimpleDateFormatter when using the UTC timezone. It looks like SimpleDateFormatter is giving the right result, but Calendar is not. I'm not sure why. I'm using the following code to generate a date using Calendar:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

In other words, March 5th, 2012 at 00:00 UTC. 
When I print this time in my local CST timezone, I get:

```
Mon Mar 05 06:00:00 CST 2012
```

This is odd because CST is UTC-6:00, so I was expecting Sunday March 4th, 2012 18:00 CST (i.e. 6 hours before midnight in the prior day). Instead I get **6 hours after UTC**.

When I use a SimpleDateFormatter like so:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    df.parse("2012-03-05");
```

I get the expected "Sunday March 4th, 2012 18:00 CST", which is **6 hours before UTC**, i.e. UTC-6:00.

Why are my results wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Calendar.HOUR` sets the hour in the 12-hour format, so you are not setting it to midnight but to 12pm.

Use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` instead or make sure to also set the am/pm value:

```
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
```

Comment: Wow, that's subtle and scary. Thanks for pointing that out. After changing it, the unit test now passes. Great!

Comment: It is. Date/time functions prior to Java 8 are really problematic. If you are going to deal heavily with them and you cannot use Java 8, you might want to look into some specific library for that like [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).